# Disable a button in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uibutton

In my project I have a button that calls a function via a IBOutlet, I need to know how can I put in the function code to make disable the button, as I identify the button (using tags?)
And what to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're slightly confused. Your button is connected to a method via an IBAction. You'll need to create a `@property` for your button and connect it to IB via an IBOutlet.

Alternatively you could utilize the `sender` argument from the IBAction. Something like this perhaps...

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *buttonThatWasPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
    buttonThatWasPressed.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simply.

```
self.yourButton.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: yes but i don't know the name of my button i have create it in IB

Comment: You would need to define an IBOutlet in your header file.  'IBOutlet NSButton *myButton'.  Connect the outlet to the button in Interface Builder.  Lastly in your implementation, you can reference the button using 'myButton' (e.g. 'myButton.enabled = NO').

Answer (score 0):

For that make code like this

```
button.enabled=NO;
```

& if you want to enable it agaian code like this

```
button.enabled=YES;
```